# Is it safe to check fields after `Future<?>` tasks are finished?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, completable-future

Is it safe to check a field modified by a task executed in a `Future<?>` after successfully calling `future.get()` ?
(Is it guaranteed to be finished setting the value, and I'm seeing the new value?)

I would check the field on the same thread as calling the `future.get()`.

Or should I only use the return value of `future.get()` and should not expect this to work like this?

Example:

```
class MyData {
    private int a;

    public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }
    public int getA() { return a; }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

        final List<MyData> objects = Arrays.asList(new MyData(), new MyData() /* ... */);

        final Future<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { objects.get(0).setA(1); return null; }, executor);
        final Future<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { objects.get(1).setA(2); return null; }, executor);
        /* ... */

        a.get();
        b.get();
        /* ... */

        // Is it safe here to check the `a` field of the objects?
        assert objects.get(0).getA() == 1;
        assert objects.get(1).getA() == 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) states

> **Memory consistency effects**: Actions taken by the asynchronous
>   computation *happen-before* actions following the corresponding
>   `Future.get()` in another thread.

Since [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get()) will only return when the corresponding computation completes (the `setA` invocation and `return`), that computation is visible through the *happen-before* relationship to any code after the call to `get`. Your call to `getA` occurs after the `Future#get`, so it'll see the results of the `setA` which happened before it.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation of `Future#get()` says:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

So it is completely safe to do the assertions once calling the `Future.get()` method since the values will be resolved by then.

Comment: The [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) is not so simple, the JVM is free to reorder instructions in certain conditions, and the caches might also be stale in the current thread. It is thus important to look at the `happen-before` relationship in the spec.